# Linked Tables via ODBC / {Sql Server} driver using TCPIP lost between MS Access 2003 restarts for mdb

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, windows-xp, odbc, dao

I have the following set-up causing issues:

- MDB or MDE frontend in msaccess 2003 (11.6566.8221) SP2
  -- run from server share folder or C:\Development
- Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services (9.00.5000.00)
- Operating System ("server"): Microsoft Windows NT 5.1 (2600) = Windows XP

I run and debug the MDB and MDE on my development machine (which is the same as the "server") connecting to it using the same Linked Table connections derived from a file DSN.

I take and run the MDB or MDE to another client (mixed client enviroment in the hospital) and it hangs and complains about odbc--connection error on the first call to a table (which is a DLookup in the start up code)

I stop the code, unhide the Database window, and 
I re-link all the tables using the File DSN I am 
carrying around on my USB drive (same as on the development machine)

- Note: the same setting in my File DSN re-creating as a new FileDNS on client = success)
- browing all the tables (opening them in Table view from Access Table tab) = works
- running all the forms again = works
- system runs like normal

** NOW **

I save the MDB again, close the MDB (leaving ACCESS open), open the MDB again
- everything works fine

I now close Access completely (no longer running), open access, and open the mdb 
-- error now happens, and any attemp to view a linked table I get the same error

Posible hint: The error message is unusual:

```
            Runtime Error '3151'
            ODBC--connection to 'SqlServerSAH0048645' failed
```

The following does work
- open the file with Startup option set to open "UserValidate" form
- in OnLoad event call ResetDefaultconnections (using down DNSless code I found)
- reset all TableDefs.connection strings to:

```
strConnectionString = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQLServer} ;Description=RAHCC_DB; SERVER=tcp:10.19.54.64,1500; UID=RAHCC_User; PWD=XXXXXXx; APP=MSACCESS; WSID=SAH0034510; DATABASE=RAHCC_DB"
```

- delete and then add new tabledef records for each linked table
- continue to open the form ---> everthing seems to work.

BUT.. as soon as I close access, and re-open --> doesn't work again.

Note
- I am restricted to what I have (is Sql Server is installed on all clients)
- I am restricted to a connection using the Sql Server driver 
- I am using Sql Server authorisation

cheers,

JonHD

Comment: Please note the original connection strip generating the error is slightly different in that SERVER=SAH0048645,1500 in the string (I have tried about 10 different versions to get it try and save, and then work again!).

Comment: I'm guessing there is a question hidden somewhere in this problem description :-)

Comment: I think sticking with the DSN-Less connection is a good idea, however if all clients have the required access then there should not be any need to re-define these linked tables everytime. Are you sure you are publishing the changes in the mdb and not attempting to alter the mde?

Comment: Yes.. I had opened the MDB on an adjacent computer which is logged in as someone else.. and the problem would occur.

Comment: At the moment I am just redefining the tabledef on opening the database, which seems to work in MDB and MDE.